# Is there a way to make a curl request in Java with a nonstandard format (IE not JSON, but a custom format)

Tags: json, http, logging, post

Say I have a custom format of JSON I'd like to use (defined in a class that extends extends `AbstractStringLayout` -- instead of doing something like:

```
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create("url"))
                    .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(log))
                    .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .build();
```

can we somehow set the header to be a custom content type?

Comment: A custom format like you are changing the structure of JSON?! I don't get it.

Comment: `... .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-your.custom.content.type") ...` ?